# Get template data from helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to update my template's datacontext on the onCreated hook:

```
Template.segment.onCreated(function () {
  var tp = this;

  this.test = "TEST";
  Meteor.call('getTreeCategData', function (error, data) {
    tp.ExternalapiData = data;
    tp.chart = new Chart(); 
    //...
  });
});
```

I want to keep these references on parents templates, To access them from childs templates.

Now I "update" a datacontext with the value set on the onCreated.

```
Template.segment.helpers({
  parentDatacontext: function(){
    this.chart = Template.instance().chart; //undefined
    this.apiData = Template.instance().apiData; //undefined
    //But it executed later, when I open the chrome object inspector    the reference, they are not undefined anymore 
    console.log("parentDatacontext: ", Template.instance());
    return this;
  }
});
```

My template:

```
<template name="segment">
{{#with parentDatacontext}}
{{> childtp}}
{{/with}}
</template>
```

To finally use them on child template event's handler:

```
Template.childtp.events({
    'click .js-close': function(e, tp){
        console.log(" tp parent data: ",Template.parentData(1));
    }
});
```

I'm actually stuck really soon on this process, i'm not even able to print the added attribute set on the onCreated from the helper...
I guess the helper is call by the template before the on created end...

Any idea how to fix that, or a better way to do what I want to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar)?

```
Template.segment.onCreated(function () {
  var tp = this;

  this.apiData = new ReactiveVar();
  Meteor.call('getTreeCategData', function (error, data) {
    tp.apiData.set(data);
    tp.chart = new Chart();
    //...
  });
});

Template.segment.helpers({
  parentDatacontext: function(){
    this.chart   = Template.instance().chart;
    this.apiData = Template.instance().apiData.get();

    //    data - {{with parentDatacontext}}
    // no data - {{else}}
    if (this.apiData) {
        return this;
    }
  }
});
```

And template code

```
<template name="segment">
    {{#with parentDatacontext}}
        {{> childtp}}
    {{else}}
        Loading or something...
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: Seems to work pretty well actually, give me some time to check it all before I validate! Thanks :) Do you wanted to write if(!this.apiData) to check the no data? I thought undefined was falsey with Js?

Comment: If `this.apiData` is present, we return `this` - it's not falsy value, so `{{#with ...}}` block will be rendered - if there's now `apiData`, helper return `undefined` and `{{else}}` block is rendered.

Comment: Ho yep sorry my bad, you're the incarnated truth!

Answer (score 1):

`parentDataContext()` is being executed before your `Meteor.call` is coming back, and then because your variables aren't reactive the helper doesn't get executed again.  You want to use a [reactive variable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) to store those values so the helper gets executed when the values get set by the method.

To access the new reactive variable in the child template, follow along with [this forum post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/access-parent-template-reactivevar-from-child-template/973).

Comment: your right too, but there was code example on @Radoslaw M 's answers, so I validated him. But your answers is complementary giving the reason, thanks